# How to push the object into the first array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

How can I push the Image object into the first array?

```js
//Vue (my current code)
productList.value.push(res.data.returnData.info);
var a ='Image';
var obj={};
obj[a] = res.data.returnData.image[0].ppName;
productList.value.push(obj);
```

[image]

Comment: `productList.value[0].img = obj` is not working?

Comment: @kissu its worked, how can I do it for multi?  the productList.value[0] only work on first array.

Comment: You could use a `.map` or a `.forEach` if you want to loop on all the elements of your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the screenshot shared by you, I can see it's an array of objects. So you want to merge image object properties into first object ? If Yes, Here you go **:**

```
const imageObj = {
  image: 'Image URL'
};

productList.value[0] = Object.assign(productList.value[0], imageObj);
```